# How to rewriteurl in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My project on mvc 4. there is search bar in my website. but when i searc in search bar the url is so long for eg. www.test.com/test/test?testname=abc

i want to show shot Url like example =  wwww.test.com/search?q=abc
how to change this Url

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "search?q=/{productName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "SearchResult" }
        );
```

this is not work for me. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "search/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "SearchResult" }
        );

Answer (score 0):

Do not include query string in the route. Asp.net MVC automatically maps the query string parameters to the parameters in action method in your controller.